# asp.net core and asp-route-id

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers, asp.net-core-routing

I've created a contact controller with that signature :

```cs
public IActionResult Index(string id)
```

Nothing fancy in the route table :

```cs
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

In my home view, I tried to create a link to the contact/index :

```xml
<a asp-controller="Contact" asp-route-id="3255">Contact me</a>
```

The generated link seems fine and goes to the right action.
With or without the asp-action, the generated link is :

```xml
<a href="/Contact/Index/3255">Contact me</a>
```

But the id is not set.
But when I copy the link and do a "paste and go to", the id parameter is set.
It also works if I view the page source and click on the link generated.
It does not work when I click the link on the page.

Can you tell me what's wrong, please?

Answer (score 13):

Given the configured routes,

the route needs to include the `action`

```xml
<a asp-controller="Contact" 
   asp-action="Index" 
   asp-route-id="3255">Contact me</a>
```

Which should generate

```cs
<a href="/Contact/Index/3255">Contact me</a>
```

Comment: but we have default action: Index?

Comment: Your default action **isn't optional**. It will only be set when you call  /Contact, but not when you do /Concact/1, because the 2nd parameter now would be treated as action. And there is no action called "1". But your route tells it to take the id from the **3rd** parameter. Don't confuse **optional** with **default value**

Comment: @isthat: if your id has a constraint (i.e. guid, int) you could use `routes.MapRoute(name: "noAction", template: "{controller=Home}/{id:int}", defaults: { action: "Index" });`, but with string id it doesn't work as it would also match /Contact/Edit and you'd get "Edit" as id instead.

Comment: @Tseng I edited the question. With or without 'asp-action', the generated link is what it should be (this is because the "Index" action is the default if not specified.